# Proper place of if in clean coding

Tags: java, coding-style

I have a question related to some "best practices" if we talk about ifs and clean code. What is a good practice (especially if we talk about Java):

```
public void foo(...){
.
.
   if (something){
     callfunction();
   }
.
.
}
```

or

```
public void foo(...){
.
.
callfunction();
.
.
}
```

In the second case we have 'if' inside callfunction(). Is there any good practice related to this case?

Comment: I prefer the first method, but that's just me. Also, this question is prone to opinionated/biased answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best advice I can give you is to name your functions clearly.  If your function does anything extra, then that should be mentioned in the function name to avoid confusion.

For example:

```
void sendEmail(Person person);
```

I'd expect this to send an e-mail, and nothing else.  If `person` is `null`, I'd expect this function to fail, and not silently do nothing.  A function that does nothing in some cases is better named:

```
void trySendEmail(Person person);
```

Or:

```
void sendEmailIfPersonValid(Person person);
```

A good way to signal problems that should be resolved by the caller of your function is to check for nonsense inputs in your function:

```
void sendEmail(Person person) {
    if(person == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("person cannot be null");
    }
    if(!person.hasEmail()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("person must have an email address");
    }


    // code to send email here
}
```

If you're still learning, then have a look at documentation for functions in `java.*` packages, they're extremely well documented and generally follow best practices.